# Copy value from one database to another using MySQL CLI

Tags: mysql

I have two databases `fooDB` and `barDB`, both having a structurally identical table named `options`. I want to copy the value of one cell in `fooDB.options` to `barDB.options`. I can't use (non local) outfiles and I have two users, both having only access to one of the two databases. Copy and paste with the mouse does not work, as the value is too complex.

Any ideas, how to copy the value with the MySQL command line client? I thought of using variables, but AFAIK you can't change your user in the same CLI session. Any ideas? It should be a **simple and fast solution**: Of course I can do a mysqldump or whatever, but this is overkill for just one value (and takes too much time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to generate SQL script which updates (or inserts) required value. To generate SQL use this command (*username1* - username for fooDB database):

```
mysql -u username1 -p -N -s -r -e "SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE barDB.options SET value = ', QUOTE(value), ' WHERE id = 1;') FROM fooDB.options WHERE id = 1" > file_name.sql
```

Then you get *file_name.sql* with something like:

```
UPDATE barDB.options SET value = 'Your value here' WHERE id = 1;
```

Then just run this script (*username2* - username for barDB database):

```
mysql -u username2 -p < file_name.sql
```

---

Some used [MySQL command line options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html):

- `-N` - do not write column names in results
- `-s` - use nontabular output format
- `-r` - disable character escaping

I disable character escaping in command line options, because special characters are already escaped with [`QUOTE` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) in SELECT query.